# Meteorjs dynamically create fields in collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a companies collection that has three companies(at the moment). There is also a second collection called campaigns. Each campaign belongs to a company. Each campaign has different fields depending on what company it is. Because mongodb is schemaless does that mean that I can add whatever fields I want to the collection. Like if I created a template form for each company could I save whatever template was selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

Yes.

**Longer answer**

While MongoDB does not enforce a schema (save for the required `_id` field), it is good to have at least some schema to your documents. If you store extremely different documents in a single collection, it can make it very challenging to handle all the different document forms in your code. This usually makes development much harder.

Typically companies have common data associated with them, so you will still have a common schema between them. But each company can expand upon that base schema. Just be sure to appropriately handle all of the potential null values for fields in your code.

Comment: When you say handle potential null values you mean on insert, any fields without values should be set to null?

Comment: No, I mean on read. If one document has field `foo`, and others do not, you have to check that the fields exists. You can't assume it.